# Is it safe to resize a partition while writing to it?

Tags: parallelism, resize2fs

I'm working on a script for automatically setting up Amazon Linux servers. I create them with 100gb virtual disks, but the main partition is always 8gb. No problem, I call `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1` at the start of the script to expand it to the full 100gb.

The process is fairly slow, though. Later on in my script I download various tools and components and set them up. I was wondering if it's safe to do that in parallel with the resize. Intuitively it seems like it would not be safe to write to a partition that's in the process of getting resized, but I thought I'd ask in case there's some clever magic Linux does that makes this ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enlarging a mounted volume has been officially supported for ext3 and ext4 for some time now. I don't know of any strong assessment regarding a change in safety. Obviously both the resizing and the other activities take even longer when done on parallel.

But it seems strange to me that this takes so long. In my experience shrinking is slow but enlarging fast. Maybe you should open another question about resizing optimization. Maybe you can do something about the image in order to speed up this process.

Comment: As it turns out, it was not actually the resize operation that was taking so much time but the calls to set up the swap space. Either way, I've put both in the background and the overall speed has improved.